# Retaining the state of manipulated dom elements on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi I have created a menu vertical menu that has some jQuery slideUp and slideDown functionality.The menu works well but I would like to find a way to retain its state on postback.

For example let's say a user clicks a button and it slides down and from the list a buttons that appear he clicks one and the page gets posted. This would result in the dom resetting to its initial state , which is not the effect I want.

So is there a way to maintain manipulated DOM elements state on multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, you can store the state in one or more cookies.

Comment: or post the menu information to the server, and store it in session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

- [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
- [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)
- keep it server side in [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29).